# Presented view controller gets dismissed if i move my application to background and then come to foreground in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I had a requirement to cover the screen with black layout when the user moves the application to the background **applicationDidEnterBackground** in order to maintain the privacy of some sensitive datas on the screen. So for this i made use of AppDelegate function to present with a black color in background and then remove that by dismissing it when comes to foreground **applicationDidEnterBackground**. The code is:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIViewController *blankViewController = [UIViewController new];
    blankViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:blankViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Now in my application everything is working fine but in one screen i am presenting a **ViewContollerB** on a button click by using : `[self presentViewController:webview animated:YES completion:nil];` The application as usually gets covered with black color when moving to background but when i take the application to foreground after this, then the presented **ViewContollerB** also gets dismissed . How to prevent my presented ViewController to get dismissed once coming from background?

Comment: Does this happen whenever you have more than 1 view controllers in the stack (i.e. when rootViewController presents some other view controllers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new 'UIViewController' called `OverLayViewController` and load it in
`applicationDidEnterBackground`  method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    OverLayViewController *blankViewController = [OverLayViewController new];
    blankViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    UIViewController *rvc = self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *pvc = rvc.presentedViewController;  // you may need to loop through presentedViewControllers if you have more than one
    if(pvc != nil) {
        [pvc presentViewController: blankViewController animated: NO completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: blankViewController animated: NO completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIViewController *test = [self topViewController];
    if ([test isKindOfClass:[OverLayViewController class]]) {
           [test dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
    }
}


- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

-(UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

In this case, `dismissViewContoller` code wont apply for your webview.

Comment: Sorry I did the same but the OverlayViewController does not dismiss when moving to the foreground. I want the OverlayViewController to dismiss but my WebView should not dismiss when coming to foreground

Comment: The above code should not dismiss your webview. Because this condition wont allow to dismiss.     if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[OverLayViewController class]]) {

Comment: The problem right now is when i come to foreground the OverLayViewController still shows. I dont want that

Comment: Checkout code from : https://github.com/prakashidesign/OverLayTest

Comment: Check this github. It is working and tested: https://github.com/prakashidesign/SampleWebView

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of if ([test isKindOfClass:[OverLayViewController class]]) {
           [test dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
    }

Comment: if ([test isKindOfClass:[OverLayViewController class]]). This if condition checks that whether presented view controller is OverLayViewController or not.

Comment: i have upvoted it and marked as green. Can you please upvote my question too? i need 15 points to upvote your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do the following: rootviewcontroller A presents a blank viewcontroller B. Your app goes into background, and you present viewcontroller C from there. Now B closes as A is presenting both B and C, and that is not allowed.

You will need to check if your rootviewcontroller is presenting any viewcontrollers, and if those are presenting any others recursively. You can check for those by using the property `presentedViewController` on a viewcontroller.

Personally, I would (in a base viewcontroller class that all viewcontrollers inherit from) keep a variable that checks if this one is visible (by keeping track of `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear`). If this is the one that is visible, you add a blank view on top.

Answer in Swift because I can't be trusted with Objective-C without an editor:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var appeared = false

    func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
        appeared = true
    }

    func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated: animated)
        appeared = false
    }
}
```

Then you need to fire a notification from the `AppDelegate` that is caught in this viewcontroller, and then show a blank view on top.

Comment: can you please help me with a sample code. I tried [blankViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];but still my ViewControllerB is getting dismissed along with blankViewController

Comment: Your ViewControllerB is getting dismissed when you present the blankViewController (I think)

Comment: Can you check which one is getting removed when? You can use `didMoveToParentViewController` to check if your viewControllerB is getting removed when you present the blankviewcontroller, or when you dismiss the blankviewcontroller

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please tell where to check this? inside app delegate?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmovetoparentviewcontroller